# Round Corner Button in Xamarin Native for iOS

Tags: user-interface, button, xamarin, xamarin-studio

How can I have a button like attached image in Xamarin iOS?
The content width may vary depending on text length.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `UIView` has a `CALayer` which you can retrieve with the `Layer` property.

This `CALayer` has all the things you need to make a button with a specific `CornerRadius`, `BorderWidth` and `BorderColor`:

```
var button = new UIButton();
button.SetTitle("Hello", UIControlState.Normal);
button.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
button.Layer.BorderWidth = 2f;
button.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
```